# Subdividing 3D Grid into rectangular pieces

Tags: algorithm, hpc

This seems like it should be a relatively simple solved problem, but I'm having difficulty finding a solution. I'm trying to divide an integer width 3-dimensional cubic space into a given number of integer width rectangular subdivisions. The blocks don't have to be the same size (as this isn't always possible), but the goal is that the volume of the largest subdivision is as small as possible (So its as fairly distributed as possible). On top of that, the surface area of the subdivisions should be as small as possible (which is to say, a 2x2x2 subdivision is preferred over a 1x2x4).

This is used to divide a space for distributed computing, so the purpose of these two requirements is to distribute load fairly and reduce required communication between processors . Anyway, I would appreciate any nudge in the correct direction for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question is not very clear, but you seem to be looking for either a [space partitioning algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) or a [space filling curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), possibly both.

#### more details:

The above two subjects are deeply interconnected, but depending on your exact problem, one of them might be useless.

Space partitioning algorithms and data structures are generally used in an application that manage a fixed space and that need to find which (possibly moving) objects are in which part of this space. So you split your volume recursively to allow fast retrieval (and update) of the list of objects in a section of the volume. You can even find algorithms that try to balance the number of objects per partition.

Space filling curves are all about imposing an order in the way someone scans a immutable list of multidimensional coordinates. In that case, the properties of the order (locality for example) is critical. And once you have a liner order, you can distribute by splitting it in as many chunks as you want, each cunk will still have good properties.

Both problems can be encountered in a *lot* of scientific applications so it has been researched in depth by very smart people. I'm definitely *not* an expert on those subjects, this is just the way I understand them. Hope it helps.